# Intuition behind Dvoretzky Kiefer Wolfowitz inequality

Tags: distributions, probability-inequalities

I've been reading about the Dvoretzky-Kiefer-Wolfowitz inequality, in the context of confidence bands on empirical distribution functions.

I think I understand the inequality at face value: that the probability that the empirical distribution function differs from the real distribution function by more than some amount is bounded by a function of sample size. (And a surprisingly aggressive function of sample size at that, at least to my mind).

What I'm completely lacking, though, is any sense of *why* the inequality holds. Given we're not (I think) making any assumptions about the real distribution function, apart from that it is a distribution function, I don't really see why we can say anything useful about it at all! It probably doesn't help that I've yet to find a comprehensible proof of the theorem (my definition of comprehensible is that which might be understood by a competent physicist!)

So, can anyone point me towards a readable proof? Or perhaps supply a hint as to the intuition behind this inequality?

Answer (score 4):

Consider an i.i.d. sample $X_{1}, \dots, X_{n}$ from a distribution with CDF $F\left(x\right)$, and let
\begin{equation}
\widehat{F}_{n}\left(x\right) = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\mathbb{I}_{X_{i} \leq x}
\end{equation}
denote the usual empirical distribution function. The [Dvoretzky-Kiefer-Wolfowitz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality) states that
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Pr}\left(\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left\{\sqrt{n}\left|\widehat{F}_{n}\left(x\right) - F\left(x\right)\right|\right\} > \epsilon\right) \leq 2e^{-2\epsilon^{2}}
\end{equation}
for all $\epsilon > 0$. To provide some intuition behind this result, first recognise that for any $x$ such that $F\left(x\right) \in \left(0, 1\right)$, the Central Limit Theorem (or alternatively using the weaker [De Moivre–Laplace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem)) gives that
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{n}\left(\widehat{F}_{n}\left(x\right) - F\left(x\right)\right) \overset{\mathrm{d}}{\to} \mathcal{N}\left(0, F\left(x\right)\left(1 - F\left(x\right)\right)\right)
\end{equation}
since $\widehat{F}_{n}\left(x\right)$ is essentially the sample proportion of observations not greater than $x$, which we can compute to have variance
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Var}\left(\widehat{F}_{n}\left(x\right)\right) = \dfrac{F\left(x\right)\left(1 - F\left(x\right)\right)}{n}
\end{equation}
(eg. by the binomial distribution). The takeaway here is that $\widehat{F}_{n}\left(x\right)$ will be approximately Gaussian for large $n$. Now, we use the fact that for a Gaussian random variable $Y \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma^{2}\right)$, a well-known two-sided concentration inequality is given by
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Pr}\left(\left|Y - \mu\right| > \varepsilon\right) \leq 2\exp\left(-\dfrac{\varepsilon^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\right)
\end{equation}
for all $\varepsilon > 0$. As an aside, this inequality can be proven using the moment generating function of a Gaussian distribution in combination with the [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) to obtain the one-sided tail inequality, and then [Boole's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality) for the two-sided tail inequality. See for example (2.9) of [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mjwain/stat210b/Chap2_TailBounds_Jan22_2015.pdf) to obtain further details.

Here is where the 'intuitive' step comes in. If we treat $\widehat{F}_{n}\left(x\right)$ as actually being Gaussian and apply the concentration inequality for Gaussians, we will recover the Dvoretzky-Kiefer-Wolfowitz inequality. Note that $F\left(x\right)\left(1 - F\left(x\right)\right)$ is maximised at $F\left(x\right) = 1/2$, hence $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}F\left(x\right)\left(1 - F\left(x\right)\right) = 1/4$. So this gives
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}\left(\widehat{F}_{n}\left(x\right)\right) &= \dfrac{F\left(x\right)\left(1 - F\left(x\right)\right)}{n} \\
&\leq \dfrac{1}{4n}
\end{align}
Treating $\widehat{F}_{n}\left(x\right)$ as Gaussian and plugging it into the concentration inequality gives for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Pr}\left(\left|\widehat{F}_{n}\left(x\right) - F\left(x\right)\right| > \varepsilon\right) \leq 2\exp\left(-\dfrac{\varepsilon^{2}}{2\operatorname{Var}\left(\widehat{F}_{n}\left(x\right)\right)}\right)
\end{equation}
Taking the worst-case supremum over $x$ on either side separately:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Pr}\left(\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left|\widehat{F}_{n}\left(x\right) - F\left(x\right)\right| > \varepsilon\right) &\leq 2\exp\left(-\dfrac{\varepsilon^{2}}{2\sup_{x'\in\mathbb{R}}\operatorname{Var}\left(\widehat{F}_{n}\left(x'\right)\right)}\right) \\
&\leq 2\exp\left(-\dfrac{\varepsilon^{2}}{2/\left(4n\right)}\right) \\
&= 2e^{-2n\varepsilon^{2}}
\end{align}
Applying the substitution $\epsilon = \sqrt{n}\varepsilon$ then yields the Dvoretzky-Kiefer-Wolfowitz inequality as originally claimed:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Pr}\left(\sqrt{n}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left|\widehat{F}_{n}\left(x\right) - F\left(x\right)\right| > \epsilon\right) \leq 2e^{-2\epsilon^{2}}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51628/24197) might help you to understand its origin. You will need to fill some details up, though.

Another reference of interest with a formal proof of an improved version of the inequallity is

> Massart, P. (1990). [The Tight Constant in the Dvoretzky-Kiefer-Wolfowitz Inequality](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-18/issue-3/The-Tight-Constant-in-the-Dvoretzky-Kiefer-Wolfowitz-Inequality/10.1214/aop/1176990746.full). *Annals of Probability* 18: 1269-1283.

The Kolmogorov-Smirnov distribution is not as simple as one would love it were and the results involving this distribution tend to be not-straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at those. Although I think you might overestimate the competence of a competent physicist :-)

Comment: @JonyEpsilon I see your point. The KS distribution is unfortunately very difficult. I hope this helps anyway.